# How to retrieve a file via REST from the services module?

Tags: 7, files, services

Which URL format should I use when retrieving a file via the services module?
I figured that it would be formatted like this:

```
http://<domain>/<endpoint>/file/fid
```

I've tried several file ids but all I get is an empty result.   Is this the correct url format for retrieving a file?

Services module version is 3.

Comment: Do you want to download the file?

Comment: I managed to get this working in the end.  I used the poster plugin to request the url and received a message saying that the file doesn't exist.  I'd been using the wrong file ids!  I had looked at the wrong drupal database to choose the file ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working in the end.  I used the poster plugin to request the url and received a message saying that the file doesn't exist.  I'd been using the wrong file ids!  I had looked at the wrong drupal database to choose the file ids.